# Will swagger use default values passed in default keyword?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, specifications, swagger-editor

I am using the below spec definition for one of my request paylods:

```
    Request:
      properties:
        tag:
            type: string
        id:
            type: string
            default: test
        value:
            type: string
```

In the spec, once i define default this way, i expect the spec to pass default value as test for id input, when client doesn't pass any value for this parameter (id). Is my understanding right?

If not, whats the definition of default in spec?

I was playing a little here:

https://editor.swagger.io/

and when i pass default values for User: , they are still not used. Rather they are just displayed in sample response.

What is the significance of this keyword?